# python `print` does not work in loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have multi loops in together and a sleep in the most inner  loop. for example:

```
from time import sleep

for i in range(10):
    print i,
    for j in range(-5,5):
        if j > 0:
            print '.',
        else:
            print 'D',
        sleep(1)
    print ''
```

if you run the code, you may expected to get `i` value after it `D` sleep 1 second and another `D` and again sleep until to the end.

but the result is difference, it waits 10 seconds and prints the whole line of `0 D D D D D D . . . .` and waiting again to printing next line.

I found the comma at the end of printing causes this problem. How can I solve it?

Comment: what output do you expect, it prints a new line on each iteration for me

Comment: every `j` iterate? it prints on every `i` iteration but I need prints on every `j`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because of existence of comma, the output buffers until a `\n`.

You should flush the `stdout` after every print or use `sys.stdout.write` and flush buffer.

Define your print method:

```
import sys

def my_print(text):
    sys.stdout.write(str(text))
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

and at the end of line print a `\n`

Comment: it did not work with me, I tried flushing the output but nothing happens

Answer (score 3):

The problem using `print <something>,` is buffering and printing only when the result is ready to be printed.

You can solve it using `print_function` from `__future__` (which will be in compliance with Python 3 as well):

```
from __future__ import print_function
from time import sleep
import sys

for i in range(10):
    print(i, end='')
    for j in range(-5,5):
        if j > 0:
            print('.', end='')
        else:
            print('D', end='')
        sys.stdout.flush()
        sleep(1)            
    print('')
```

Comment: You still need a `sys.stdout.flush()` to make it look like it's printing incrementally. If using Python 3.3+, then supplying a `flush=True` to print is also available.

Comment: @JonClements thanks I wasn't aware of it since it works fine without the flush in python 2.7.5

Comment: It's `sys.stdout` that does the buffering. Using `print()` as a function does not change the buffering behaviour, but you *can* use `flush=True` in newer Python versions to force a flush. Use `sys.stdout.flush()` on versions where the `flush` argument is not available (like Python 2).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest override print just after import with below coe

```
import sys
def print_msg(*args,end='\n'):
    for item in args:
        sys.stdout.write(str(item)+' ')
    sys.stdout.write(end)
    sys.stdout.flush()

print = print_msg
```