# How to see print output from generator before ending the cycle?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

I'm trying to print debug information inside a generator working with big list of data. But, I can see the result only when the generator finishes.

I am using python 3 and my code is as follows:

```
def generator():
    while 1:
        print ('.', end='')
        time.sleep(1)
        yield 1

for a in generator():
    print ('|', end='')
```

Result:

```
^C.|.|.|.|.|
```

Equivalent PHP7 code works as expected:

```
function generator()
{
    while (1) {
        echo '.';
        sleep(1);
        yield 1;
    }
}

foreach (generator() as $item) {
    echo '|';
}
```

Result:

```
.|.|.|.|.|^C
```

How to print debug information in realtime for each iteration of the generator's cycle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

I believe that you have a similar issue to that question: [Print statements not working when serve_forever() is called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43197518/print-statements-not-working-when-serve-forever-is-called/43250818#43250818) (although by the title is not apparent...)

Try to flush your prints:

```
print ('.', end='', flush=True)

print ('|', end='', flush=True)
```

---

**flush**

> The method flush() flushes the internal buffer, like [stdio's fflush](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fflush.htm). This may be a no-op on some file-like objects.

It **forces** the `print()` function to print whatever have been buffered up to that point to the `stdout` of your machine.